# how to create a view of entities and nodes

Tags: views, entities

I need to create a view which displays both entity type data and node data. Is this possible? I know how to create a view of either entities or nodes, but not together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node are entities. Likely a Node View has access to node-specific properties while an Entity View only has access to fields and generic properties (or properties exposed through the Entity API).

If you can link your entities to nodes using a relation that is exposed as a relationship in a Node/Entity View, you should be able to have view results consisting of data from both a entities and nodes.

Comment: How does this work in detail?